# OS X icon on insertion of CD

Tags: macos, icons, cd

I am trying to create the following behavior:

- Insert a CD on Mac OS X (Leopard and up) machine.
- Upon reading of CD, display a custom icon for the inserted CD
- Drag in an application from CD to Application folder.
- Run application

Up until here I know it can be done but here is the twist:

In the OSX next session, I would like to insert that same CD and display a DIFFERENT CD icon.

I was thinking of having some kind of agent after installation that would monitor this specific CD or some kind of script.

Any ideas in terms of solving this problem ?
thx